# How to sum each list in a nested list?

Tags: list, prolog

What I am trying to do is basically get the some of the list of list, if that makes sense.

What I am trying to achieve is `sum([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])`. Should return:

```
Number Of Lists: 3
List 1
3
List 2
7
List 3
11....etc
```

I can get the Number of Lists which is fairly simple but I'm not quite sure how to  loop through the List and then for each List add the number up. Am I making this more complicated than it actually is?

Answer (score 2):

In SWI-Prolog you can use `maplist` and `sumlist`;

```
?- maplist(sumlist, [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]], Lengths).
Lengths = [3, 7, 11].
```

Now you can pretty-print `Lengths` the way you like.

To learn how `maplist` and `sumlist` are implemented, just call `listing(maplist)` and `listing(sumlist)`.

Comment: SWI-Prolog seems to have elements of functional programming  (higher-order functions), right?

Comment: @Yasir: Yes, it has call/N which lets you implement things like maplist/N

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's a beginner question, I have made the following code in Visual Prolog, though it's generic and is supposed to work on all major implementations of Prolog:

```
domains
  ilist=integer*
  ilistlist=ilist*

predicates
  mapsum(ilistlist, ilist, ilist)
  reverse(ilist,ilist,ilist)
  sum(ilist,integer,integer)

clauses
  reverse([],L,L).
  reverse([X|Xs], A, R):-
    A1 = [X|A],
    reverse(Xs, A1, R).

  sum([], A, A).  
  sum([X|Xs], A, R):-
    Y = X + A,
    sum(XS, Y, R).

  mapsum([], A, R):-
    reverse(A, [], R).
  mapsum([X|Xs], A, R):-
    sum(X, 0, Sum),
    A1 = [Sum|A],
    mapsum(Xs, A1, R).

goal
  mapsum([[9,5,3,6],[8,4],[2,7],[]], [], R).
```

Result is:

```
R=[23,12,9,0]
1 Solution
```

This code works for any number of elements in the inner lists and handles empty lists properly.

I think it doesn't make much sense to have lists inside a list, just a list of sums will do.
The asterisk in `integer*` in Visual Prolog means that you want the list of `integer`s.

In the goal you call the main predicate `mapsum` providing it with 3 lists in a list, an empty list (accumulator) and an unbound variable `R`; the latter will get the result.

`mapsum` in each iteration retrieves the head `X` of the list you provided in the goal, and evaluates sum of its (list) elements, then it creates a new list `A1`, which's a combination of the accumulator `A` and a sum of the head you just evaluated, then it tail-calls itself with the rest of list elements (tail), a new accumulator `A1` and the yet unbound variable `R`.

When `mapsum` approaches the bound condition, when the list (first argument) is empty, it reverses the list, and binds the result of reverse to unbound variable `R`.

I think you'll sort out how `sum` and `reverse` work yourself.

Comment: Certainly, there are other ways to approach the problem, e. g. you may go the functional way, but I haven't fiddled with the other Prolog implementations yet.

Comment: It cannot work (as is) on anything else than Visual Prolog (Prolog = dynamically typed, sometimes [dynamically] compiled language, Visual-Prolog = statically typed, statically compiled, syntactically Prolog-resembling language. "Proskell++" ;-)). Normally whats in 'clauses' goes into source files (or get assert-ed), and the goals are asked interactively or get called by someting. Rest are type declarations unrecognized by standard Prolog. SWI Prolog has [gradual] typing listed as goal, stay tuned (unless you want C++ like performance and Windows[only]-oriented implementation = Visual Prolog).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the number of built-in predicates you use to just "is":

```
sum_list([], []).
sum_list([[A,B]|Rest], [Current|RestResult]) :-
      Current is A + B,
      sum_list(Rest, RestResult).

?- sum_list( [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], X ).
X = [3, 7, 11].
```

Tested in SWI-Prolog.

Comment: Can you bring some reasons why one would want to limit the use of built-ins? Portability?

Comment: For practical reasons portability.  For less practical ones, it makes for a great learning exercise.